# how to handle option types in JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane

I need a way of writing some code to handle the event when a button in the JOptionPane is clicked. I'm actually using a JOptionPane to insert username and password which if correct and ok button is clicked, the JOptionPane vanishes and the parent JFrame remains active and if the cancel button is clicked the program exits. my sample code below only shows the JOptionpane and clicking any button just closes it
`JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        //Create a label with text (Username)
        JLabel username = new JLabel("Username");

```
    //Create a label with text (Password)
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Password");

    //Create text field that will use to enter username
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(12);

    //Create password field that will be use to enter password
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(12);

    //Add label with text (username) into created panel
    panel.add(username);

    //Add text field into created panel
    panel.add(textField);

    //Add label with text (password) into created panel
    panel.add(password);

    //Add password field into created panel
    panel.add(passwordField);

    //Show JOptionPane that will ask user for username and password
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, panel, "Enter username and password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);`
```

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 4):

Those dialogs return an `int` value that can interpreted to be one of the following:

- `YES_OPTION`
- `NO_OPTION`
- `CANCEL_OPTION`
- `OK_OPTION`
- `CLOSED_OPTION`

For instance,

```
final int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, panel, "Enter username and password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    // OK was pressed. Now do stuff.
}
else if(option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
    // Cancel was pressed. Now do stuff.
}
```

Comment: And even add a switch statement to remove the yucky IF smell.

Comment: @SpencerKormos, Not sure how using a switch statement would remove the "yucky" smell...

Comment: Thanks @Moonbeam let me try that out

Comment: @Moonbeam NoIFs always smell better than If-elseif-ad_nauseum.

Comment: @SpencerKormos, That seems pretty subjective to me.

Comment: @Moonbeam More often than not, switches are clearer and the compiler can optimize. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/15820/should-i-use-switch-statements-or-long-if-else-chains

Comment: cant we use state pattern for such delegation.

Comment: @SpencerKormos, I don't think OP is concerned about micro-optimizations.

Comment: @Moonbeam, there is still one problem. how do I stop the JOptionPane from closing when I don't want it to and how do I make it close when I want it to

Answer (score 2):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) to the rescue:

> Returns:
>
> an int indicating the option selected by the user

compare the result with the constants defined in JOptionPane (`OK_OPTION`, `CANCEL_OPTION`, `CLOSED_OPTION`, etc.)